# Not a proper alignment of only one entry in a tabular environment

Tags: tables

I have a tabular environment with three rows and three columns.  I have the proper alignment of the lower-case Roman numerals except for `viii`.  How do I correct this?  (I want to keep the tabular environment.)

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{array}


\begin{document}

\noindent \textbf{4.) }Express the following fractions as decimals. \\
\noindent \hspace*{2em}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.75in}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{3ex}
\begin{tabular}{@{}r@{}lr@{}lr@{}l}
\textbf{i.) }   &   $\displaystyle{\frac{1}{4}}$
&
\textbf{ii.) }  &   $\displaystyle{\frac{3}{2}}$
&
\textbf{iii.) } &   $\displaystyle{\frac{18}{5}}$ \\[1.2\normalbaselineskip]
\textbf{iv.) }  &   $\displaystyle{\frac{36}{10}}$
&
\textbf{v.) }   &   $\displaystyle{\frac{15}{5}}$
&
\textbf{vi.) }  &   $\displaystyle{\frac{75}{100}}$ \\[1.2\normalbaselineskip]
\textbf{vii.) } &   $\displaystyle{\frac{45}{20}}$
&
\textbf{viii.) }&   $\displaystyle{\frac{20}{8}}$
&
\textbf{ix.) }  &   $\displaystyle{\frac{3}{8}}$
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: really tabular is wrong here and you should never need to number things "by hand" like this, you are just missing so many of latex's facilities for automatic numbering linking etc

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'm a bit puzzled by the fact that the space between `}` and `&` makes a difference. Can you explain it, please?

Comment: @gernot it's an `r` column, the template of which ends in `\unskip` so that a space at the end of a cell is ignored but if you go `abc {} &`  then there are two space tokens each adding one word-space, and the `\unskip` just removes the second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add a space between the closing brace `}` and the following `&`. But I suggest to remove the formatting from the individual entries and to add it to the column specifiers. Then it is irrelevant whether there is an intervening space or not.

```
\begin{tabular}{@{}>{\bfseries}r<{.) }@{}l>{\bfseries}r<{.) }@{}l>{\bfseries}r<{.) }@{}l}
 i   &   $\displaystyle{\frac{1}{4}}$
&
ii  &   $\displaystyle{\frac{3}{2}}$
&
iii &   $\displaystyle{\frac{18}{5}}$ \\[1.2\normalbaselineskip]
iv  &   $\displaystyle{\frac{36}{10}}$
&
v   &   $\displaystyle{\frac{15}{5}}$
&
vi  &   $\displaystyle{\frac{75}{100}}$ \\[1.2\normalbaselineskip]
vii &   $\displaystyle{\frac{45}{20}}$
&
viii&   $\displaystyle{\frac{20}{8}}$
&
ix  &   $\displaystyle{\frac{3}{8}}$
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: How is what I have in my post following `viii.)` different from what I have following `ix.)`?

Comment: To be consistent with the formatting in my file, I want the space to be in the `\bfseries` style.  Should I replace `{\ }` with `{\bfseries\ }`?

Comment: @AgalnamedDesire In the one entry, you have `viii.) }&`, in the other one `ix.) }  &`; note the space between `}` and `&` in the latter case. My guess would have been that the spaces between `}` and `&` are ignored anyway, but apparently they are not (the number of spaces is irrelevant, once there is at least one).

Comment: @AgalnamedDesire Well, just try, the computer will not explode; computer science is sometimes experimental ;-) In this case you can also move `.)` to the  column specifiers. See my edited answer.

Comment: I did "try" replacing `\textbf{{viii.) }&` with `\textbf{viii.) } &`, including the extra space, and the display obtained was what I wanted.  That is odd that a space is needed in the code.

Answer (score 1):

Now it works. The difference is a space after `\textbf{viii.) }`:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{array}


\begin{document}

\noindent \textbf{4.) }Express the following fractions as decimals. \\
\noindent \hspace*{2em}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.75in}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{3ex}
\begin{tabular}{@{}r@{}lr@{}lr@{}l}
\textbf{i.) }   &   $\displaystyle{\frac{1}{4}}$
&
\textbf{ii.) }  &   $\displaystyle{\frac{3}{2}}$
&
\textbf{iii.) } &   $\displaystyle{\frac{18}{5}}$ \\[1.2\normalbaselineskip]
\textbf{iv.) }  &   $\displaystyle{\frac{36}{10}}$
&
\textbf{v.) }   &   $\displaystyle{\frac{15}{5}}$
&
\textbf{vi.) }  &   $\displaystyle{\frac{75}{100}}$ \\[1.2\normalbaselineskip]
\textbf{vii.) } &   $\displaystyle{\frac{45}{20}}$
&
\textbf{viii.) } &   $\displaystyle{\frac{20}{8}}$
&
\textbf{ix.) }  &   $\displaystyle{\frac{3}{8}}$
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

BTW: Do you **really** need both full stop  and right parenthesis (`.)`) in your enumerations?

Answer (score 1):

gernot has already pointed out the problem. I have simplified your code further so that this shall not occur again.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}

\newcounter{taskcounter}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\newcolumntype{T}{>{\makebox[3em][r]{\textbf{\roman{taskcounter}.)}\stepcounter{taskcounter}} $\displaystyle}l<{$}}

\begin{document}
\section{Express the following fractions as decimals}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{3}%
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.75in}%
\setcounter{taskcounter}{1}%
\begin{tabular}{@{}TTT}
\frac{1}{4} & \frac{3}{2} & \frac{18}{5} \\
\frac{36}{10} & \frac{15}{5} & \frac{75}{100} \\
\frac{45}{20} & \frac{20}{8} & \frac{3}{8}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```